# Extensionless URL settings in Sitefinity 4.x and above

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4, sitefinity-5

Does anyone know where the settings related to Extensionless URLs are found in Sitefinity 4.x and above? I'm looking at 'Advanced Settings' in the backend and I can't find them.

A website that I recently upgraded from Sitefinity 4.4 to 5.3 is suddenly showing .aspx extensions for some pages and a 404 error for others. I can't add content to newly created pages as it's showing the 404 when I try to add some content to the page draft.

Answer (score 1):

Sitefinity by default is extensionless and given that some pages have .aspx and some don't, have you checked its not due to some faulty url-rewrite rules that may have been added to the web.config ?

Just to be on the safe side, you could check your PagesConfig.config file (located in /App_Data/Sitefinity/Configuration) that it looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pagesConfig 
 xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration"
 xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type"
 config:version="5.3.3900.0"
 defaultFrontendTemplateId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 defaultBackendTemplateId="0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
 enableBrowseAndEdit="False"
/>
```

(Naturally the 0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 will be actual valid guids on your end)

Further more, you can swap your web.config out for [one](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19007909/web533900.config) that comes out of the box to verify.

If some pages due to errors have been given extensions, you can simply remove them by using a snippet like [this one](http://www.sitefinityguru.com/blog/2012/04/17/removing-or-changing-sitefinity-page-extensions) from @selaromdotnet.

Jochem